# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, docx, pywin32

Why do I keep getting
`pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)`?

Here is my code. I am trying to use docx2pdf to convert pdf files to docx.

```
import win32com.client
#from win32 import _win32sysloader
#from win32 import win32api
#from docx2pdf import convert

def translator():

    print('reconverting')
    convert("C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\btab083 (1).docx", "C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\btab083 (1).pdf")
    print('success')

translator()
I'm using Python 3.11.4 on Windows 10.
```

Here is the entire error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\translatorTest.py", line 55, in <module>
    translator()
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\translatorTest.py", line 53, in translator
    convert("C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\btab083 (1).docx")
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 106, in convert
    return windows(paths, keep_active)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 19, in windows
    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 118, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

As you can see I tried different import statements of(commented out) as solutions. I found them online. No matter what order I tried them I kept getting No module named 'pywintypes' or No module named '_win32sysloader'.

I installed pywin32 using `pip install pywin32`. I also used `python pywin32_postinstall.py -install`, `pip install win32`, `python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install` and `python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32.`

I also tried pip install pywintypes.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Word installed?

Comment: @DS_London I installed Word and now it works. Thanks.